# Controller spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ros interface

Tags: ros, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, ROS jade and GAZEBO 5.0
I followed step by step the tutorial of ROS Control in GAZEBO, http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_control&cat=connect_ros. when I execute the command line "roslaunch rrbot_control rrbot_control.launch"
nothing happens and I am not able to control the rrbot robot. Also I see this warning: Controller spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ros interface. I am sure that I added the plugin libgazebo_ros_control.so as they said in the tutorial. Any help would be greatly appriciated. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225002/controller-spawner-couldn%27t-find-the-expected-controller_manager-ros-interface/) by [bahom](https://answers.ros.org/users/25516/bahom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2016-01-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) on 2016-01-26**:
I think there is a problem with Jade and ros_control with Gazebo if you install it from packages (see this link : http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing). I use ros indigo with gazebo6.

**Comment by [bahom](https://answers.ros.org/users/25516/bahom/) on 2016-01-26**:
Thanks for your feedback. You're right the package gazebo_ros_control hasn't been released yet. But how can I proceed now??

**Comment by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) on 2016-01-26**:
You can install ros indigo (that's what I did when I found there was no gazebo_ros_control released for ros Jade)

**Comment by [bahom](https://answers.ros.org/users/25516/bahom/) on 2016-06-14**:
Thanks for your suggestion @Brosseau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks so much for your help. Finally I turned it out by building this package (gazebo_ros_control) from source

---

Originally posted by [bahom](https://answers.ros.org/users/25516/bahom/) with karma: 36 on 2016-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1